# How could I get a job revising test questions?

Tags: united-states, standards

I have spent most of my life in Denver, Colorado in the United States.

When I was in 8th grade, all students, including myself, took an exam called the "CSAP." This exam was not written by any one teacher, nor was the exam created on a school-by-school basis. All children in public school the entire state of Colorado took the exact same exam.

I found a mistake on the math section of the CSAP. I wish I could tell you all of the details, but I do not remember everything now. The question was about basic geometry. There was a picture of a rectangle. The exam instructions said "do ***NOT*** assume that shapes are drawn to scale." However, there was literally no-way to compute the quantity they asked for if the rectangle was not drawn to scale (the length of rectangle was exactly twice as long as the width, or something like that). I stared at the problem for more than 5 minutes.

It happened to be that the teacher who was overseeing my group of student was also my math teacher. While taking the CSAP, this was not always the case. While the the CSAP was administered, the teachers were reduced to the role of glorified baby-sitters. There only responsibility was to ensure that we did not throw our exams in the trash, or cheat on them, or sing loudly.

I showed my teacher the geometry question. At first, he told me that I was not allowed to ask him question, but I refused to take no for an answer. I gave him my exam, and I asked him to look at it. He stared at it for a long time before eventually agreeing with me.

When I was in high school, I was constantly finding mistakes on exam questions written by my teachers.
My instructors did not like me very much.
The same thing happened in college.

I have discovered various "***anti-patterns***" for school exams. The people who write exams always make the same types of mistakes.

One example of of an ***anti-pattern*** involves fill-in the blank questions.

Imagine taking an exam in anything other than English or STEM (math or science).
Maybe the exam is on:

- economics
- psychology
- world history

You will find fill in the blank questions where the the supposedly "correct" answer has incorrect English grammar.

1. Take the word or phrase from the answer key
2. Substitute the "correct" answer into the blank portion of a fill-in-the-blank question.
3. try read the resulting sentence out-loud without becoming tongue-tied.

The correct answer for economics fill-in-the-blank is not actually correct English grammar.

I have decided that I want a job reading SAT, ACT, GRE, questions etc...

I want to read questions, I spot the mistakes, and then I tell publishers how to fix them.

Less than a week ago, I took an exam for a tutoring job. I found a lot of mistakes in the exam questions. For example, there was a passage from one of Mark Twain's famous books. You couldn't possibly answer the question from reading the passage. The question was only answerable if you read a different part of the book which was a few chapters later.

I have no idea what the job title would be if I had a job.

How would I get a job like that?

When I was a student it was very important to me that my score be based on my ability, or lack-thereof. I often received a B instead of A because of a deficiency on my teacher's part instead of my own.

---

BONUS EXAMPLE:

I was once got a question wrong in math class, because I wrote "0.5" instead of "1/2."

Comment: Have you tried looking up the companies that make the various standardized tests and looking at their Career pages?  The College Board, for example, does the SAT and PSAT, the AP exams, and a number of other standardized tests.  They've got a careers page https://careers.collegeboard.org/.

Comment: Honestly - I would start by correcting the grammatical errors in your question first and then contact one or more of the publishing entities/companies that create, market and distribute the tests/exams/literature used in high school and college..

Comment: I note that people **taking** exams also make the same, or similar, mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a specific kind of proof-reading work. The comments so far suggest the sort of places you might look for people offering that kind of work (exam publishers, testing boards). That answers the "where to look", but not "how to get a job".

It sounds like you understand the sort of role that might be offered : "I want to read questions, I spot the mistakes, and then I tell publishers how to fix them."
The part an interviewer will be looking for is that last clause. In the question I can see a lot of problems you've identified, but I didn't see any suggested ways to resolve them or how they could have been done differently. That would be the part to emphasise in any applications.

Any fool can tell someone they're doing it wrong - and many do. The marketable talent lies in showing people how they could do it better.

There's another question I would ask if I was the hiring manager doing the interview : "Tell me about a time you did something wrong, and how other people showed you a better way."

Your employer would be the examination board, but your immediate clients would be the people you were trying to convince to change what they had written. It will be useful - and probably essential - to be able to demonstrate an understanding of their perspective.